# Retrieve array object in a table from another table data id using a where clue in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

> Question: I have two tables how to fetch a customer's data using order's table user_id

```
  "order": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 5
    }
  ],


  "customers": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Mohamed Raazi",
            "phone": "777",
        }
    ],
```

**Following code will return only the last object of an array, i need to display all the objects from user table using a where condition in customers table**

```
        for ($x=0; $x<count($orders); $x++){
            $customer = User::where('id',$orders[$x]->user_id)->get(); 
        }
```

Comment: it seems user and orders are one-to-many relationship. Build the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `::whereIn`-method where you can provide an array of IDs to and get all the users with the provided IDs.

First you would have to reformat the `$orders` array that you have so that it contains only user IDs. I am guessing that you are using Eloquent to fetch the orders, then you can use the pluck-function in your Eloquent-statement:

```
$userIds = Order::where('statement', true)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
```

Please note that the where-statement is not real, I just want to illustrate how you can call the pluck-method.

Another alternative is that you use the map function on the `$orders`-collection and return only user IDs:

```
$userIds = $orders->map(function ($order) {
    return $order->user_id;
});
```

Once you have your user IDs in an array/collection you can use it in the whereIn-statement:

```
$users = Users::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```

Then this would give you all the users that that are connected to the orders you have in your order-collection.